# What is the application Bundle and Resources folder

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsimageview

My question is about the application bundle in a project. I was reading about that and can understand some basic things (I'm not a native english speaker). I can understand that the `resources folder` is used to hold the files that will be used in the project, e.g. media files (images, audio, video, etc.) and should be in the `application bundle` to be identified.

So, what is the point if I want to use images and another resources in my project? In my [other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444836/nsimage-returns-nil-even-when-png-file-is-in-resource-folder), I can't use them by referencing with `NSImage imageNamed:`.

I have used the following with no success loading my files:

- NSBundle methods
- `imageNamed:@"string"` with/without file extension
- the images are in resources folder

I'm learning `Cocoa` and `Objective-C`, and of course this is different to `C++` or `Java` when I want to create an ImageIcon or a QImage.

Comment: Can you provide us some code, you have tried and didn't work? Also make sure, the files are inside the `Target Membership`. Just select the file and look in the `File Inspector` on the right.

Comment: NSImageView *accessory = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,200,55)];
    [accessory setImageScaling:NSScaleToFit];
    [accessory setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"logosH.png"]];
    [myAlert setAccessoryView:accessory];

the weirdest thing is that i manage to achieve load one of those images using IB over a NSImageView, but in code, no

Comment: the file is checked in the target membership

Comment: @user3078163 Add that information to your question by clicking `edit` and then revising your question (instead of adding comments).

Answer (score 1):

I may not have completely understood the issue, so correct me if I am wrong. I believe the problem has to do with your image's target membership or how you're retrieving the image in your code.

Adding an image to your project target will appropriately copy the resource at compile time. To add the image to your target, select it in the file navigator and then reveal the *Utilities Panel*. On the Utilities Panel, select the *File Inspector* Tab. Look for the **Target Membership** section and ensure that the image is selected for the desired targets:

[image: Xcode 5 Target Membership]

Do you mean that you can't use the `NSImage imageNamed:` method to retrieve resources? If so, you can retrieve the resource like this (from the main resource bundle):

```
NSString *imageName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image1" ofType:@"png"];
NSImage *imageObj = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
```

---

It also looks like you already have [a good answer to your other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20456017/814730).